# Python 2D Gaussian Fit with NaN Values in Data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian

I'm very new to Python but I'm trying to produce a 2D Gaussian fit for some data. Specifically, stellar fluxes linked to certain positions in a coordinate system/grid. However not all of the positions in my grid have corresponding flux values. I don't really want to set these values to zero in case it biases my fit, but I can't seem to set them to `nan` and still get my Gaussian fit to work. This is the code I'm using (modified slightly from [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData)):

```
import numpy
import scipy
from numpy import *
from scipy import optimize

def gaussian(height, center_x, center_y, width_x, width_y):
    width_x = float(width_x)
    width_y = float(width_y)
    return lambda x,y: height*exp(-(((center_x-x)/width_x)**2+((center_y-y)/width_y)**2)/2)

def moments(data):
    total = nansum(data)
    X, Y = indices(data.shape)
    center_x = nansum(X*data)/total
    center_y = nansum(Y*data)/total
    row = data[int(center_x), :]
    col = data[:, int(center_y)]
    width_x = nansum(sqrt(abs((arange(col.size)-center_y)**2*col))/nansum(col))
    width_y = nansum(sqrt(abs((arange(row.size)-center_x)**2*row))/nansum(row))
    height = nanmax(data)
    return height, center_x, center_y, width_x, width_y

def fitgaussian(data):
    params = moments(data)
    errorfunction = lambda p: ravel(gaussian(*p)(*indices(data.shape)) - data)
    p, success = optimize.leastsq(errorfunction, params)
    return p

parameters = fitgaussian(data)
fit = gaussian(*parameters)
```

My flux values are in a 2D array called `data`. The code works if I have `0` instead of `nan` values in this array, but otherwise my `parameters` always come out as `[nan nan nan nan nan]`. If there's a way to fix this, I would really appreciate your insight! The more detailed the explanation, the better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should have a look at scikit learn's gaussian mixture model. Its fairly simple to use. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The obvious thing to do is remove the NaNs from `data`. Doing so, however, also requires that the corresponding positions in the 2D `X`, `Y` location arrays also be removed:

```
X, Y = np.indices(data.shape)
mask = ~np.isnan(data)
x = X[mask]
y = Y[mask]
data = data[mask]
```

Now you can use `optimize.leastsq` (or the newer, simpler `optimize.curve_fit`) 
to fit the data to the model function:

```
p, success = optimize.leastsq(errorfunction, params, args=(x, y, data))
```

---

For example, if we generate some random `data` with NaNs

```
data = make_data(shape)
```

so that

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

looks like

[image]

with the white spots showing where there are NaN values, then

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
np.set_printoptions(precision=4)


def gaussian(p, x, y):
    height, center_x, center_y, width_x, width_y = p
    return height*np.exp(-(((center_x-x)/width_x)**2+((center_y-y)/width_y)**2)/2)

def moments(data):
    total = np.nansum(data)
    X, Y = np.indices(data.shape)
    center_x = np.nansum(X*data)/total
    center_y = np.nansum(Y*data)/total
    row = data[int(center_x), :]
    col = data[:, int(center_y)]
    width_x = np.nansum(np.sqrt(abs((np.arange(col.size)-center_y)**2*col))
                        /np.nansum(col))
    width_y = np.nansum(np.sqrt(abs((np.arange(row.size)-center_x)**2*row))
                        /np.nansum(row))
    height = np.nanmax(data)
    return height, center_x, center_y, width_x, width_y

def errorfunction(p, x, y, data):
    return gaussian(p, x, y) - data

def fitgaussian(data):
    params = moments(data)
    X, Y = np.indices(data.shape)
    mask = ~np.isnan(data)
    x = X[mask]
    y = Y[mask]
    data = data[mask]
    p, success = optimize.leastsq(errorfunction, params, args=(x, y, data))
    return p

def make_data(shape):
    h, w = shape
    p = 50, h/2.0, w/2.0, h/3.0, w/5.0
    print('Actual parameters: {}'.format(np.array(p)))
    X, Y = np.indices(shape)
    data = gaussian(p, X, Y) + np.random.random(shape)
    mask = np.random.random(shape) < 0.3
    data[mask] = np.nan
    return data

shape = 100, 200
data = make_data(shape)
X, Y = np.indices(shape)
parameters = fitgaussian(data)
print('Fitted parameters: {}'.format(parameters))
fit = gaussian(parameters, X, Y)
```

yields

```
Actual parameters: [  50.       50.      100.       33.3333   40.    ]
Fitted parameters: [ 50.2908  49.9992  99.9927  33.7039  40.6149]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all the values that don't have a corresponding flux value. Removing pairs of values won't matter if you don't have anything on the y-axis at that point.

This should remove all values that don't have flux values if the empty values are equal to `''`

```
# assumes data.shape = (1, 3) where data[:,0:1] is the x,y axis
# data[:,2] contains the flux values
data = numpy.delete(data, numpy.where(data[:,3] == ''), axis=0)
```

this will do the job if empty values are equal to `nan`

```
data = numpy.delete(data, numpy.where(data[:,3] == numpy.nan), axis=0)
```