# How to ignore certain values (e.g. NaNs) when curve fitting?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, physics

take a look at the image below. On the left, you see a plot by `plt.imshow` of a 2D array called `img_roi`. On the right, I first identify the maximum and then cut along the vertical, i.e.

```
centre = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(img_roi, axis=None), img_roi.shape)
x_profile = img_roi[:, centre[1]]
```

I then fit a normal distribution to that curve. As can be seen, since every second pixel is off by a certain factor, the fit doesn't look good, even though the curve is clearly Gaussian.

For completeness, the data is

```
x_profile = [ 1.50000000e+00 -7.00000000e-01 -2.70000000e+00  2.80000000e+00
  3.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01  2.50000000e+00  1.10000000e+00
 -1.00000000e-01  8.10000000e+00  6.90000000e+00  7.53000000e+01
  2.14000000e+01  2.31000000e+02  4.68000000e+01  4.84900000e+02
  8.91000000e+01  7.47500000e+02  1.16400000e+02  8.62900000e+02
  1.13100000e+02  7.01300000e+02  8.74000000e+01  4.46700000e+02
  4.70000000e+01  2.01900000e+02  1.69000000e+01  4.68000000e+01
  7.50000000e+00  1.60000000e+00  3.50000000e+00  4.20000000e+00
  4.00000000e-01  9.10000000e+00  7.10542736e-15  5.50000000e+00
  2.60000000e+00  5.00000000e-01  2.50000000e+00  1.40000000e+00]
```

My **goal** is to fit a Gaussian by using the bright pixel values only, **without** losing information that they are not neighbors but second-nearest neighbors.

[image]

I know that there are some "easy" fixes, e.g.: Taking every second pixel, fitting, and then re-scaling.

```
x_profile_squish = x_profile[::2] - Fit to this
```

What doesn't work is setting the "not so bright" pixels to zero. I could scale them to match the bright ones, but that misses the point. It's clear how to do the Gaussian fit.

**Question**
Is there a way to set every second pixel to `empty` or some value that Python simply discards when doing a fit? Or is there another way to tell scipy to **ignore** certain values when fitting?

Edit:
Here is the full 2D data (it is quite large)

```
img_roi = [[ 3.10000000e+00  1.60000000e+00 -3.90000000e+00  4.10000000e+00
  -4.10000000e+00  3.10000000e+00  4.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01
   1.60000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01
   3.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00  9.00000000e-01  2.70000000e+00
  -1.80000000e+00 -6.00000000e-01  3.50000000e+00  2.00000000e+00
   1.30000000e+00 -7.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01  7.10542736e-15
  -4.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01  2.50000000e+00
  -2.20000000e+00  7.00000000e-01  2.40000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01
   7.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01  2.70000000e+00  7.00000000e-01
   1.50000000e+00  1.40000000e+00  1.30000000e+00  9.00000000e-01]
 [ 7.00000000e-01  2.10000000e+00  1.30000000e+00  1.20000000e+00
   7.00000000e-01 -1.30000000e+00  3.20000000e+00 -3.90000000e+00
   2.50000000e+00 -2.40000000e+00  3.00000000e-01  1.70000000e+00
   6.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01  1.00000000e-01
   1.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  2.00000000e-01  2.00000000e+00
   1.10000000e+00  2.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01  1.20000000e+00
   1.20000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01
  -4.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01 -9.00000000e-01
   3.10000000e+00  4.00000000e-01  1.10000000e+00  6.00000000e-01
   2.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01]
 [-3.30000000e+00 -3.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01
   1.40000000e+00  4.00000000e-01  1.40000000e+00 -6.00000000e-01
   5.00000000e-01 -5.00000000e-01  2.20000000e+00  2.00000000e-01
   1.60000000e+00  3.00000000e-01 -2.60000000e+00  4.00000000e-01
   9.00000000e-01  3.10000000e+00 -5.00000000e-01  2.00000000e-01
   1.70000000e+00  8.00000000e-01 -1.50000000e+00  7.10542736e-15
   6.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01  1.70000000e+00 -1.10000000e+00
   1.10000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  1.10000000e+00  2.00000000e-01
   2.60000000e+00  1.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01
   3.50000000e+00  5.30000000e+00  4.10000000e+00  4.90000000e+00]
 [-4.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01  1.40000000e+00
   8.00000000e-01  1.40000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  3.30000000e+00
  -4.00000000e-01  1.40000000e+00 -4.00000000e-01  3.20000000e+00
   1.10000000e+00  2.70000000e+00  8.00000000e-01  1.50000000e+00
   4.00000000e-01  1.50000000e+00 -4.40000000e+00  1.60000000e+00
   3.00000000e-01  3.90000000e+00 -4.00000000e-01  2.00000000e+00
  -9.00000000e-01  1.00000000e-01  2.00000000e-01  2.80000000e+00
   5.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01  8.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01
   5.20000000e+00  2.80000000e+00  5.70000000e+00  3.10000000e+00
   4.60000000e+00 -6.00000000e-01  9.60000000e+00  1.30000000e+00]
 [ 7.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01  2.30000000e+00
  -2.40000000e+00  7.00000000e-01  8.00000000e-01  2.00000000e-01
   3.20000000e+00  1.00000000e-01  1.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01
   1.40000000e+00  1.00000000e+00 -4.20000000e+00  8.00000000e-01
   4.00000000e-01  3.30000000e+00  5.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01
  -4.00000000e-01 -4.00000000e-01 -4.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01
   1.00000000e+00  8.00000000e-01  3.70000000e+00  7.00000000e-01
   9.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01  1.20000000e+00  6.20000000e+00
   1.10000000e+00  4.70000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  9.90000000e+00
   1.80000000e+00  1.31000000e+01 -5.00000000e-01  8.70000000e+00]
 [-6.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00  9.00000000e-01  8.00000000e-01
   0.00000000e+00 -6.00000000e-01  1.40000000e+00  6.00000000e-01
   1.80000000e+00  1.60000000e+00  5.20000000e+00  3.70000000e+00
  -8.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01 -3.70000000e+00 -8.00000000e-01
   5.00000000e-01  3.10000000e+00  3.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01
   6.00000000e-01  2.20000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01  1.00000000e+00
  -7.00000000e-01  1.20000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  2.00000000e-01
   3.60000000e+00  1.90000000e+00  8.50000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01
   7.60000000e+00  1.30000000e+00  1.48000000e+01  3.80000000e+00
   1.24000000e+01  3.00000000e-01  1.33000000e+01  2.60000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01  1.50000000e+00  6.00000000e-01
   3.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01  1.40000000e+00  3.20000000e+00
  -4.60000000e+00  9.00000000e-01  1.10000000e+00  4.00000000e-01
   1.60000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01  2.20000000e+00
   6.00000000e-01  2.00000000e+00  1.10000000e+00  7.00000000e-01
   2.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -2.90000000e+00 -5.00000000e-01
   7.00000000e-01  3.20000000e+00  7.00000000e-01  2.60000000e+00
  -1.70000000e+00  4.30000000e+00  1.20000000e+00  5.00000000e+00
   1.80000000e+00  9.00000000e+00  1.60000000e+00  1.36000000e+01
   8.00000000e-01  2.18000000e+01  2.50000000e+00  2.26000000e+01]
 [ 5.40000000e+00 -6.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01
  -2.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01  2.00000000e+00
   1.00000000e+00  8.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01  4.10000000e+00
  -4.00000000e-01  3.10000000e+00 -2.70000000e+00  3.00000000e+00
   1.10000000e+00  2.80000000e+00  2.40000000e+00  4.00000000e-01
   2.90000000e+00 -1.70000000e+00 -7.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01
   1.10000000e+00  7.00000000e-01  2.30000000e+00  1.70000000e+00
   5.00000000e-01 -3.10000000e+00  7.00000000e-01  2.70000000e+00
   4.90000000e+00  2.20000000e+00  1.17000000e+01  7.00000000e+00
   1.53000000e+01  2.60000000e+00  2.80000000e+01  4.40000000e+00]
 [ 3.30000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01
   2.80000000e+00  1.90000000e+00  2.10000000e+00  5.00000000e-01
   2.30000000e+00 -8.00000000e-01  3.20000000e+00  4.10000000e+00
   1.00000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01  1.50000000e+00  8.00000000e-01
   1.30000000e+00  3.20000000e+00 -6.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01
   2.30000000e+00  1.00000000e-01  3.60000000e+00  1.20000000e+00
   1.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01  1.00000000e+00  8.00000000e-01
   1.60000000e+00  1.90000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  6.70000000e+00
  -6.00000000e-01  1.37000000e+01  6.00000000e-01  1.55000000e+01
   6.80000000e+00  2.90000000e+01  4.10000000e+00  2.77000000e+01]
 [-6.00000000e-01  2.00000000e+00  3.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01
   0.00000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  1.50000000e+00  2.80000000e+00
   1.40000000e+00  1.70000000e+00  1.00000000e-01  2.50000000e+00
  -3.00000000e-01  3.00000000e+00  2.40000000e+00  2.60000000e+00
   6.00000000e+00  1.70000000e+00  4.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
   1.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01 -1.40000000e+00
   1.03000000e+01  3.10000000e+00  1.11000000e+01  8.00000000e-01
   8.20000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  9.20000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
   1.29000000e+01  6.00000000e-01  1.79000000e+01  4.90000000e+00
   2.35000000e+01  5.30000000e+00  2.31000000e+01  7.40000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e-01  2.50000000e+00  2.80000000e+00  4.10000000e+00
  -3.00000000e+00 -8.00000000e-01  2.90000000e+00 -3.00000000e-01
   2.40000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  3.20000000e+00  2.90000000e+00
  -5.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01 -4.00000000e-01  6.50000000e+00
  -3.00000000e-01  4.30000000e+00  1.20000000e+00  4.60000000e+00
  -6.00000000e-01  3.20000000e+00  2.50000000e+00  1.97000000e+01
   4.40000000e+00  2.58000000e+01  4.80000000e+00  3.30000000e+01
   1.00000000e-01  2.34000000e+01  0.00000000e+00  1.72000000e+01
   3.60000000e+00  2.74000000e+01 -2.00000000e-01  3.04000000e+01
   5.70000000e+00  3.94000000e+01  5.00000000e+00  3.15000000e+01]
 [ 2.60000000e+00  3.60000000e+00 -4.00000000e-01  2.60000000e+00
   5.00000000e-01  2.30000000e+00  2.30000000e+00  7.00000000e-01
   4.00000000e-01  1.20000000e+00  9.00000000e-01  0.00000000e+00
   5.20000000e+00  1.60000000e+00  5.30000000e+00  2.90000000e+00
   5.90000000e+00  5.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01  3.50000000e+00
   8.00000000e-01  3.40000000e+00  2.31000000e+01  5.10000000e+00
   5.82000000e+01  1.01000000e+01  7.56000000e+01  7.70000000e+00
   6.34000000e+01  8.50000000e+00  4.76000000e+01  7.50000000e+00
   4.03000000e+01  6.00000000e+00  4.40000000e+01  3.90000000e+00
   4.30000000e+01  3.40000000e+00  4.10000000e+01  9.70000000e+00]
 [ 3.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01 -4.10000000e+00  1.00000000e-01
  -6.00000000e-01  2.90000000e+00  2.10000000e+00  3.00000000e-01
   3.10000000e+00 -4.00000000e-01 -1.10000000e+00  4.50000000e+00
   1.90000000e+00  2.90000000e+00  1.70000000e+00  4.10000000e+00
  -1.00000000e-01  5.60000000e+00  1.50000000e+00  2.50000000e+00
   1.30000000e+00  2.47000000e+01  1.17000000e+01  7.51000000e+01
   1.50000000e+01  1.15200000e+02  2.28000000e+01  1.30900000e+02
   1.29000000e+01  1.09500000e+02  1.21000000e+01  7.60000000e+01
   1.13000000e+01  6.12000000e+01  6.30000000e+00  5.38000000e+01
   4.20000000e+00  4.44000000e+01  4.70000000e+00  4.59000000e+01]
 [ 9.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01  1.80000000e+00  5.00000000e-01
   2.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01
   8.00000000e-01  2.30000000e+00  1.80000000e+00  2.80000000e+00
   1.20000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  4.90000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01
   5.20000000e+00  4.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00  3.70000000e+00
   2.45000000e+01  1.48000000e+01  8.45000000e+01  3.01000000e+01
   1.60100000e+02  3.88000000e+01  2.24200000e+02  3.32000000e+01
   2.21900000e+02  2.77000000e+01  1.59000000e+02  2.22000000e+01
   1.14200000e+02  1.60000000e+01  8.95000000e+01  1.01000000e+01
   5.86000000e+01  1.03000000e+01  5.06000000e+01  5.00000000e+00]
 [ 3.10000000e+00  2.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01 -1.20000000e+00
   3.50000000e+00  4.00000000e-01  2.00000000e+00  3.00000000e-01
  -3.00000000e-01  1.10000000e+00  1.50000000e+00  9.00000000e-01
   1.00000000e+00  4.40000000e+00  2.50000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01
   2.90000000e+00  2.00000000e-01  1.90000000e+00  1.76000000e+01
   1.19000000e+01  8.60000000e+01  2.25000000e+01  2.11800000e+02
   4.67000000e+01  3.03900000e+02  4.53000000e+01  3.38200000e+02
   3.98000000e+01  2.85500000e+02  2.98000000e+01  2.05900000e+02
   2.00000000e+01  1.42400000e+02  1.32000000e+01  9.68000000e+01
   1.12000000e+01  5.57000000e+01  6.40000000e+00  4.90000000e+01]
 [-4.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -2.90000000e+00  3.00000000e+00
   4.00000000e-01  3.10000000e+00  1.40000000e+00  8.00000000e-01
  -1.10000000e+00  8.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   4.10000000e+00  2.10000000e+00  5.30000000e+00  2.80000000e+00
  -1.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00  1.60000000e+01  1.42000000e+01
   7.20000000e+01  2.89000000e+01  2.05000000e+02  5.11000000e+01
   3.58600000e+02  7.71000000e+01  4.28900000e+02  7.63000000e+01
   4.32700000e+02  5.68000000e+01  3.30600000e+02  4.14000000e+01
   2.33900000e+02  3.12000000e+01  1.50400000e+02  1.80000000e+01
   8.39000000e+01  9.40000000e+00  5.02000000e+01  6.70000000e+00]
 [ 1.60000000e+00  5.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01
   6.00000000e-01  1.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  6.00000000e-01
  -6.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01  1.20000000e+00  8.00000000e-01
   2.30000000e+00  1.00000000e-01  3.40000000e+00  6.00000000e-01
   1.90000000e+00  4.60000000e+00  6.70000000e+00  5.37000000e+01
   1.62000000e+01  1.82300000e+02  5.04000000e+01  3.82500000e+02
   6.97000000e+01  5.40600000e+02  7.82000000e+01  5.44800000e+02
   7.65000000e+01  4.89900000e+02  5.67000000e+01  3.57800000e+02
   3.81000000e+01  2.19400000e+02  2.04000000e+01  1.48500000e+02
   1.32000000e+01  6.97000000e+01  6.10000000e+00  4.51000000e+01]
 [ 1.00000000e-01 -2.90000000e+00 -4.00000000e-01 -3.90000000e+00
   3.30000000e+00  8.00000000e-01 -9.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01
   5.00000000e-01  1.80000000e+00  2.90000000e+00  1.00000000e-01
   9.00000000e-01 -1.60000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00
   4.30000000e+00  6.00000000e+00  3.76000000e+01  2.17000000e+01
   1.44300000e+02  4.89000000e+01  3.33400000e+02  8.32000000e+01
   5.66200000e+02  1.09800000e+02  6.62000000e+02  1.16500000e+02
   6.38900000e+02  8.49000000e+01  4.89100000e+02  6.72000000e+01
   3.42200000e+02  4.13000000e+01  2.06000000e+02  2.02000000e+01
   1.09900000e+02  1.01000000e+01  4.38000000e+01  4.80000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01 -3.30000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   1.90000000e+00  2.20000000e+00  1.30000000e+00  7.10542736e-15
   7.00000000e-01  0.00000000e+00 -3.70000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01
   1.80000000e+00  3.80000000e+00  2.60000000e+00  2.50000000e+00
   3.10000000e+00  1.96000000e+01  9.80000000e+00  9.64000000e+01
   2.91000000e+01  2.77500000e+02  6.83000000e+01  5.17200000e+02
   8.77000000e+01  6.69000000e+02  1.14300000e+02  7.31000000e+02
   7.97000000e+01  6.14700000e+02  6.81000000e+01  4.53100000e+02
   4.72000000e+01  2.86100000e+02  3.10000000e+01  1.53000000e+02
   1.61000000e+01  6.66000000e+01  6.10000000e+00  3.09000000e+01]
 [ 3.30000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01  8.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01
  -3.60000000e+00  1.10000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00
   1.40000000e+00  3.00000000e-01  1.60000000e+00  1.00000000e-01
   0.00000000e+00 -5.00000000e-01  1.20000000e+00  6.00000000e-01
   8.40000000e+00  6.40000000e+00  5.73000000e+01  2.63000000e+01
   1.93700000e+02  6.28000000e+01  4.26900000e+02  9.50000000e+01
   6.18500000e+02  1.27700000e+02  7.38200000e+02  1.29800000e+02
   6.68100000e+02  9.69000000e+01  5.17600000e+02  6.49000000e+01
   3.69900000e+02  5.00000000e+01  2.18600000e+02  2.18000000e+01
   9.12000000e+01  9.20000000e+00  3.50000000e+01  2.50000000e+00]
 [ 8.00000000e-01 -2.90000000e+00  1.30000000e+00  2.50000000e+00
   1.50000000e+00 -5.80000000e+00  1.60000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01
   5.00000000e-01 -9.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01
   1.80000000e+00  3.00000000e-01  2.70000000e+00  7.20000000e+00
   3.00000000e-01  2.53000000e+01  1.51000000e+01  1.14600000e+02
   3.40000000e+01  2.82100000e+02  6.08000000e+01  5.11400000e+02
   9.37000000e+01  6.59200000e+02  1.05600000e+02  7.09900000e+02
   9.21000000e+01  5.78900000e+02  6.34000000e+01  4.09200000e+02
   4.77000000e+01  2.77700000e+02  2.03000000e+01  1.27500000e+02
   1.08000000e+01  5.07000000e+01  7.00000000e+00  1.34000000e+01]
 [-3.10000000e+00  5.00000000e-01 -8.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01
   6.00000000e-01  4.90000000e+00 -1.30000000e+00  5.00000000e-01
  -4.00000000e-01  1.60000000e+00  1.00000000e-01 -4.00000000e-01
   1.30000000e+00  1.00000000e-01  2.70000000e+00  3.50000000e+00
   9.70000000e+00  5.40000000e+00  5.08000000e+01  2.58000000e+01
   1.67700000e+02  5.84000000e+01  3.53500000e+02  9.03000000e+01
   5.34100000e+02  1.15000000e+02  6.15400000e+02  1.13100000e+02
   5.86700000e+02  9.07000000e+01  4.21400000e+02  5.94000000e+01
   2.93800000e+02  3.84000000e+01  1.50200000e+02  1.29000000e+01
   6.51000000e+01  5.70000000e+00  1.63000000e+01  2.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.10000000e+00  9.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01  1.40000000e+00
  -1.20000000e+00  1.60000000e+00  8.00000000e-01 -4.00000000e-01
   4.00000000e-01 -9.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01 -4.00000000e-01
   7.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01  4.80000000e+00
   4.00000000e-01  2.11000000e+01  1.01000000e+01  8.35000000e+01
   2.32000000e+01  2.22400000e+02  4.82000000e+01  3.86300000e+02
   7.43000000e+01  4.94700000e+02  7.49000000e+01  5.27900000e+02
   6.54000000e+01  4.16900000e+02  4.92000000e+01  2.88200000e+02
   3.27000000e+01  1.70000000e+02  1.68000000e+01  7.52000000e+01
   7.10000000e+00  2.23000000e+01  2.70000000e+00  5.00000000e+00]
 [-4.00000000e-01  1.70000000e+00  1.50000000e+00  1.20000000e+00
  -5.00000000e-01 -7.00000000e-01 -1.20000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
   1.10000000e+00  1.30000000e+00  4.00000000e-01  2.00000000e-01
   1.10000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  1.60000000e+00  5.00000000e-01
   6.50000000e+00  5.80000000e+00  2.94000000e+01  1.96000000e+01
   1.01200000e+02  3.35000000e+01  2.30600000e+02  5.66000000e+01
   3.44300000e+02  6.62000000e+01  3.91000000e+02  7.62000000e+01
   3.59600000e+02  5.39000000e+01  2.44500000e+02  3.76000000e+01
   1.66200000e+02  1.88000000e+01  7.38000000e+01  9.60000000e+00
   2.49000000e+01 -6.00000000e-01  5.70000000e+00  3.70000000e+00]
 [-3.90000000e+00 -1.40000000e+00  6.00000000e-01 -4.30000000e+00
   3.20000000e+00  1.00000000e-01 -2.20000000e+00  8.00000000e-01
   2.00000000e-01  3.50000000e+00  2.20000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01
   2.60000000e+00  1.10000000e+00 -7.00000000e-01  6.50000000e+00
  -3.00000000e-01  1.62000000e+01  5.70000000e+00  4.84000000e+01
   1.29000000e+01  1.05300000e+02  2.76000000e+01  2.04400000e+02
   4.00000000e+01  2.86700000e+02  4.98000000e+01  2.74100000e+02
   4.12000000e+01  2.00200000e+02  3.19000000e+01  1.44300000e+02
   1.66000000e+01  7.23000000e+01  5.70000000e+00  2.51000000e+01
   9.00000000e-01  6.40000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00]
 [ 2.60000000e+00  7.00000000e-01 -9.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01
  -1.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01  1.70000000e+00
  -2.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01  2.40000000e+00 -6.00000000e-01
   5.70000000e+00  1.10000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01
   4.30000000e+00  3.40000000e+00  1.38000000e+01  5.10000000e+00
   3.73000000e+01  1.86000000e+01  8.89000000e+01  2.53000000e+01
   1.55600000e+02  3.42000000e+01  1.67700000e+02  2.87000000e+01
   1.50400000e+02  2.54000000e+01  1.02000000e+02  1.38000000e+01
   5.65000000e+01  5.10000000e+00  2.24000000e+01 -2.00000000e-01
   7.60000000e+00  1.30000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  2.10000000e+00]
 [ 3.30000000e+00  1.30000000e+00  2.00000000e-01  2.30000000e+00
  -2.40000000e+00  7.00000000e-01 -9.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01
   4.00000000e-01  3.20000000e+00  4.00000000e-01  5.70000000e+00
   1.40000000e+00  5.60000000e+00  2.10000000e+00  4.30000000e+00
   1.80000000e+00  7.00000000e+00 -5.00000000e-01  1.27000000e+01
   5.30000000e+00  3.72000000e+01  9.80000000e+00  6.43000000e+01
   1.13000000e+01  8.53000000e+01  1.39000000e+01  9.43000000e+01
   1.15000000e+01  6.44000000e+01  5.40000000e+00  3.70000000e+01
   5.80000000e+00  1.56000000e+01  5.00000000e-01  6.50000000e+00
  -2.10000000e+00  3.40000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01]
 [-4.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01  3.40000000e+00
  -4.10000000e+00  3.00000000e-01  7.10542736e-15 -7.00000000e-01
   1.30000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01  1.60000000e+00  3.10000000e+00
   4.60000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  1.03000000e+01  2.60000000e+00
   5.90000000e+00  1.60000000e+00  4.20000000e+00  2.50000000e+00
   4.90000000e+00  7.20000000e+00  1.71000000e+01  1.05000000e+01
   3.25000000e+01  8.60000000e+00  3.43000000e+01  7.10000000e+00
   3.49000000e+01  5.80000000e+00  1.75000000e+01  2.70000000e+00
   6.50000000e+00  1.80000000e+00  3.20000000e+00  2.30000000e+00
  -2.00000000e-01  2.20000000e+00  1.10000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01]
 [-8.00000000e-01  4.10000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  1.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  2.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01  1.60000000e+00
  -1.20000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  2.30000000e+00  5.70000000e+00
  -5.00000000e-01  5.50000000e+00  2.90000000e+00  6.70000000e+00
   3.10000000e+00  8.70000000e+00  2.10000000e+00  5.30000000e+00
   2.10000000e+00  5.20000000e+00  6.00000000e-01  8.40000000e+00
   4.50000000e+00  1.25000000e+01  3.60000000e+00  1.36000000e+01
   4.00000000e-01  6.30000000e+00  3.00000000e-01 -5.00000000e-01
   2.00000000e+00  1.70000000e+00  1.90000000e+00 -3.00000000e-01
   1.70000000e+00  8.00000000e-01  2.10000000e+00  4.50000000e+00]
 [ 2.60000000e+00 -2.70000000e+00  3.10000000e+00 -2.10000000e+00
   2.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e+00 -6.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01
  -4.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01  5.00000000e+00  3.20000000e+00
   5.10000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  9.50000000e+00  1.50000000e+00
   1.03000000e+01  2.70000000e+00  1.25000000e+01  5.00000000e-01
   9.90000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  1.00000000e-01  1.20000000e+00
   6.00000000e-01  3.00000000e+00  8.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01
   1.30000000e+00  1.70000000e+00 -4.30000000e+00  2.00000000e-01
   3.00000000e-01  3.30000000e+00 -1.40000000e+00 -2.40000000e+00
   3.30000000e+00  2.20000000e+00  4.50000000e+00  1.50000000e+00]
 [ 5.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01 -5.00000000e-01  1.00000000e-01
   9.00000000e-01  8.00000000e-01  1.80000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01
   2.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01  2.20000000e+00  5.70000000e+00
   3.00000000e-01  4.20000000e+00  3.00000000e-01  1.59000000e+01
   6.00000000e-01  1.37000000e+01  1.60000000e+00  1.19000000e+01
   1.70000000e+00  8.50000000e+00  4.00000000e-01  3.70000000e+00
   1.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01  2.00000000e-01 -7.00000000e-01
   1.80000000e+00  7.00000000e-01  1.80000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   3.00000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  1.70000000e+00  5.00000000e-01
   1.60000000e+00  1.50000000e+00  3.00000000e-01  3.80000000e+00]
 [ 3.10000000e+00 -4.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01 -4.00000000e-01
   6.00000000e-01  1.60000000e+00  6.00000000e-01 -1.10000000e+00
  -4.00000000e-01  8.00000000e-01  1.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+00
   7.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01  9.70000000e+00  2.10000000e+00
   1.30000000e+01  1.00000000e-01  1.75000000e+01  4.00000000e-01
   1.58000000e+01  6.00000000e-01  1.12000000e+01  1.80000000e+00
   8.00000000e+00 -3.00000000e+00  4.00000000e+00  2.20000000e+00
   3.90000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  4.40000000e+00  1.00000000e-01
  -1.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01  0.00000000e+00  1.90000000e+00
   4.30000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  5.20000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01]
 [ 8.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01 -4.00000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01
   1.00000000e+00  3.10000000e+00  3.00000000e-01 -5.00000000e-01
   1.80000000e+00 -5.00000000e-01 -7.00000000e-01  3.30000000e+00
  -3.70000000e+00  4.70000000e+00  1.70000000e+00  9.90000000e+00
  -5.00000000e-01  1.18000000e+01  2.20000000e+00  1.34000000e+01
   1.20000000e+00  1.32000000e+01  1.20000000e+00  9.10000000e+00
   3.00000000e+00  9.00000000e+00  3.60000000e+00  7.10000000e+00
   1.10000000e+00  5.20000000e+00  2.70000000e+00  6.10000000e+00
   2.10000000e+00  4.50000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  7.60000000e+00
   1.00000000e+00  5.20000000e+00  1.90000000e+00  9.30000000e+00]
 [ 5.00000000e-01  2.80000000e+00 -7.00000000e-01  0.00000000e+00
   1.00000000e-01  8.00000000e-01 -3.70000000e+00  4.00000000e-01
   4.00000000e-01  4.50000000e+00  2.20000000e+00  8.00000000e-01
  -1.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01  1.50000000e+00  2.10000000e+00
   4.20000000e+00  3.40000000e+00  1.04000000e+01  1.60000000e+00
   9.80000000e+00  3.20000000e+00  1.07000000e+01  2.80000000e+00
   1.01000000e+01  1.30000000e+00  9.40000000e+00  5.10000000e+00
   6.90000000e+00  1.70000000e+00  4.70000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
   3.80000000e+00  2.20000000e+00  5.20000000e+00  1.20000000e+00
   9.40000000e+00  5.00000000e-01  4.10000000e+00  2.40000000e+00]
 [ 8.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e+00
  -5.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01  2.90000000e+00
  -2.40000000e+00  1.40000000e+00  3.40000000e+00  1.80000000e+00
  -6.00000000e-01 -4.10000000e+00  2.30000000e+00  1.30000000e+00
   1.50000000e+00  3.60000000e+00  1.10000000e+00  7.70000000e+00
   3.80000000e+00  1.08000000e+01  1.00000000e-01  1.37000000e+01
   7.00000000e-01  9.60000000e+00  2.00000000e-01  5.30000000e+00
   2.80000000e+00  8.60000000e+00  1.70000000e+00  2.50000000e+00
   3.70000000e+00  4.30000000e+00  5.00000000e-01  4.00000000e+00
  -2.00000000e-01  4.70000000e+00  2.70000000e+00  4.30000000e+00]
 [-3.60000000e+00 -5.00000000e-01  1.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01
  -5.00000000e-01 -3.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01
   1.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01  1.00000000e-01 -5.10000000e+00
   4.20000000e+00  1.10000000e+00  1.00000000e-01  1.90000000e+00
   7.10542736e-15  0.00000000e+00  4.60000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   6.10000000e+00  4.00000000e-01  8.00000000e+00  1.60000000e+00
   3.50000000e+00  1.20000000e+00  6.50000000e+00 -4.00000000e-01
   9.20000000e+00  8.00000000e-01  4.20000000e+00  2.40000000e+00
   4.90000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  5.80000000e+00  2.80000000e+00
   4.40000000e+00 -7.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01  7.00000000e-01]
 [-2.00000000e-01  4.00000000e-01  3.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00
  -3.60000000e+00 -4.10000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01 -1.42108547e-14
   5.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01 -4.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01
   2.20000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+00  9.00000000e-01
   5.00000000e-01  1.80000000e+00 -6.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01
   2.60000000e+00  2.70000000e+00 -8.00000000e-01  3.00000000e-01
   3.10000000e+00  4.90000000e+00  1.40000000e+00  6.90000000e+00
   5.00000000e-01  5.30000000e+00  2.20000000e+00  4.70000000e+00
   2.20000000e+00  4.50000000e+00  1.30000000e+00 -1.10000000e+00
   4.10000000e+00  7.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00  1.20000000e+00]
 [ 1.80000000e+00 -3.20000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01  1.80000000e+00
  -7.00000000e-01  8.00000000e-01  1.70000000e+00  3.40000000e+00
  -1.30000000e+00 -1.60000000e+00  4.00000000e-01  1.90000000e+00
   1.70000000e+00  2.00000000e-01 -3.80000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01
   6.00000000e-01  3.20000000e+00 -3.40000000e+00  1.10000000e+00
   2.00000000e+00  3.30000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
  -3.00000000e-01  2.10000000e+00  1.50000000e+00  2.80000000e+00
   8.00000000e-01  2.60000000e+00  4.20000000e+00 -5.00000000e-01
   6.00000000e+00  3.70000000e+00  1.30000000e+00  2.80000000e+00
   1.20000000e+00  1.80000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e-01  2.30000000e+00 -1.50000000e+00  6.00000000e-01
  -4.00000000e-01  1.50000000e+00  1.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00
  -8.00000000e-01 -6.00000000e-01  2.00000000e-01  1.10000000e+00
  -1.42108547e-14  1.20000000e+00 -3.40000000e+00  2.60000000e+00
  -2.50000000e+00  3.40000000e+00  6.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e-01
   1.00000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01 -2.90000000e+00
   2.10000000e+00  1.50000000e+00 -1.20000000e+00  2.00000000e+00
   2.80000000e+00  7.50000000e+00 -9.00000000e-01  1.10000000e+00
   3.20000000e+00  5.30000000e+00  1.80000000e+00  3.10000000e+00
  -2.40000000e+00  5.00000000e-01  8.00000000e-01  3.60000000e+00]
 [ 7.00000000e-01  9.00000000e-01 -1.00000000e-01 -4.40000000e+00
   3.20000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  2.00000000e-01  1.00000000e-01
   0.00000000e+00  7.00000000e-01  1.90000000e+00  1.50000000e+00
  -3.00000000e-01 -2.00000000e+00  2.00000000e-01 -3.90000000e+00
   3.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00 -1.00000000e-01  1.00000000e-01
   1.00000000e-01  1.20000000e+00 -2.50000000e+00  2.70000000e+00
  -3.90000000e+00  2.80000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  9.00000000e-01
   2.00000000e-01  1.30000000e+00  6.70000000e+00  2.90000000e+00
  -1.00000000e-01 -3.90000000e+00  2.00000000e-01 -2.90000000e+00
   3.10000000e+00  1.00000000e-01 -1.20000000e+00 -2.00000000e-01]]
```

Comment: what is the problem with fitting to the slice ```x_profile[::2]```?

Comment: Can you post your 2D data?

Comment: Why not: avoid slicing, avoid flattening, and fit to a 2D Gaussian multiplied by a 2D sinusoid?

Comment: @Nin17 In the end, I want to fit to the 2D version, and there you can't do an easy squish like that.

Comment: @Reinderien Added the 2D data. I am not sure how fitting to a 2D Gaussian multiplied by a 2D sinusoid would solve this problem? I.e. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Reinderien I see what you mean now. But the relevant pixels in my case are checkerboard-like, and I don't think a sinusoid can take the diagonals into account.

Comment: In that case you could fit to ```img_roi[::2, ::2]``` and then scale the result?

Comment: No because then I get every 4-th pixel. I do want every 2-nd pixel.

Comment: actually I think it would be ```img_roi[1::2, ::2]``` and ```img[::2, 1::2]``` that select the bright pixels

Comment: no you don't you get every second pixel on each axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to throw away your data. You can get pretty close, and find true 2D parameters of fit:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


modulator = np.zeros_like(img_roi)
modulator[0::2, 1::2] = 1
modulator[1::2, 0::2] = 1
modulator = modulator.ravel()


def gaussian(xy: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float, e: float, f: float) -> np.ndarray:
    x, y = xy
    return a * np.exp(-b*(x - c)**2) * np.exp(-d*(y - e)**2) * (1 + f*modulator)


xy = np.stack(
    np.meshgrid(
        np.arange(img_roi.shape[0]),
        np.arange(img_roi.shape[1]),
        copy=False,
    )
).reshape((2, -1))

initial = (100, 0.01, 20, 0.01, 20, 1)

res, _ = curve_fit(
    f=gaussian,
    xdata=xy,
    ydata=img_roi.ravel(),
    p0=initial,
)

yfit = gaussian(xy, *res).reshape(img_roi.shape)

print(res)
print(img_roi[13:25, 25:30])
print(yfit[13:25, 25:30])
```

```
[1.20827916e+02 2.74206593e-02 2.68145375e+01 3.84558433e-02
 1.87491210e+01 5.22361058e+00]
[[ 38.8 224.2  33.2 221.9  27.7]
 [303.9  45.3 338.2  39.8 285.5]
 [ 77.1 428.9  76.3 432.7  56.8]
 [540.6  78.2 544.8  76.5 489.9]
 [109.8 662.  116.5 638.9  84.9]
 [669.  114.3 731.   79.7 614.7]
 [127.7 738.2 129.8 668.1  96.9]
 [659.2 105.6 709.9  92.1 578.9]
 [115.  615.4 113.1 586.7  90.7]
 [494.7  74.9 527.9  65.4 416.9]
 [ 66.2 391.   76.2 359.6  53.9]
 [286.7  49.8 274.1  41.2 200.2]]
[[ 30.97021507 207.15496225  33.86447586 202.9835828   29.73550831]
 [288.61537124  49.84088629 315.58735551  48.83726443 277.10898205]
 [ 64.29949346 430.08933303  70.3084767  421.42883179  61.73602987]
 [513.78112515  88.72468062 561.79553397  86.93807457 493.29792788]
 [ 98.14351263 656.46672494 107.31532239 643.24777146  94.23077074]
 [672.39975922 116.11647639 735.23756183 113.77829497 645.59282483]
 [110.13018257 736.64369995 120.4221831  721.81026143 105.73956146]
 [646.94545859 111.72078222 707.40447938 109.47111477 621.15332492]
 [ 90.85353635 607.70520491  99.34407565 595.46813862  87.23142799]
 [457.61315794  79.02505425 500.37849939  77.43376489 439.36924019]
 [ 55.10208456 368.56929224  60.25154196 361.14759036  52.90529917]
 [237.9688182   41.09475097 260.20772804  40.26724581 228.48158325]]
```

You can even establish "corrected" data views that remove the modulating checkerboard:

```
corrected_orig = img_roi / (1 + res[5]*modulator.reshape(img_roi.shape))
corrected_fit = (gaussian(xy, *res) / (1 + res[5]*modulator)).reshape(img_roi.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting approach. One issue is that the "white" pixels in the checkerboard are not equal, but are split in two categories: red and blue channels. I think to way to modify the code above is then to say: ```modulator_blue[0::2, 0::2] = 1``` (blue), ```modulator_red[1::2, 1::2] = 1``` (red). Then, I add a second parameter to curve fit, i.e. ```2d_gauss() * (1 + f*modulator_blue + g*modulator_red)```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a related post that describes a solution that is applicable to `scipy.optimize.leastsq` routines.
I first set the irrelevant data points to `nan` and then mask them using `mask = ~np.isnan(img_roi)`.

This is sufficient for the purpose described above.

Link to answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30791245/12460839

Comment: I do not recommend this approach. I don't think that those points are irrelevant.